# How to call C# delegate to pass array of strings from native C simplest way?

Tags: c#, interop, pinvoke, marshalling, native

I know this can be done by mallocing in C, passing malloced pointer to delegate with parameter type IntPtr, marshalling to string[] and then freeing malloced memory with separate, exported C-function from managed code.

My question is: Can this be done simpler way? E.g. :

- C# delegate parameter is of type string[]?
- no separate free function to call from managed code

EDIT: I tried with delegate signature:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
MyManagedDelegate(string[] values, int valueCount)
```

and fucntion in C:

```
void NativeCallDelegate(char *pStringValues[], int nValues)
{
    if (gSetStringValuesCB)
        gSetStringValuesCB(pStringValues, nValues);
}
```

calling it in C:

```
char *Values[]= {"One", "Two", "Three"};
NativeCallDelegate(Values, 3);
```

This results in that i can use only 1st string in array.

Comment: Maybe you can use an array of `BSTR`, and perhaps the marshaller will be able to do the work for you

Comment: There just is no conceivable reason to do it this way.  Your C code simply allocates strings before calling the delegate, destroys them afterwards.  Or keeps the storage around for the next time, that's fine as well.  It is a pure C code implementation detail.  All that the pinvoke marshaller does is create the managed strings and/or array from the native one.

Comment: I would really appreciate a complete answer. Thanks.

Comment: Could you make your requirements clearer? Who calls what? 
If you want to call C# from C, then  decorating with DllExport would be good enough.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's how to do it properly, I'll give a full example so it's reproductible.

## The C side

```c
typedef void(*setStringValuesCB_t)(char *pStringValues[], int nValues);

static setStringValuesCB_t gSetStringValuesCB;

void NativeCallDelegate(char *pStringValues[], int nValues)
{
    if (gSetStringValuesCB)
        gSetStringValuesCB(pStringValues, nValues);
}

__declspec(dllexport) void NativeLibCall(setStringValuesCB_t callback)
{
    gSetStringValuesCB = callback;
    char *Values[] = { "One", "Two", "Three" };
    NativeCallDelegate(Values, 3);
}
```

Nothing fancy here, I just added the necessary glue code and left the rest alone.

## The C# side

```cs
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate void MyManagedDelegate(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeParamIndex = 1)]
    string[] values,
    int valueCount);

[DllImport("NativeTemp", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void NativeLibCall(MyManagedDelegate callback);

public static void Main()
{
    NativeLibCall(PrintReceivedData);
}

public static void PrintReceivedData(string[] values, int valueCount)
{
    foreach (var item in values)
        Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

The trick lies in the marshaling part:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate void MyManagedDelegate(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeParamIndex = 1)]
    string[] values,
    int valueCount);
```

The `MarshalAs` attribute tells the .NET marshaler the following:

- `UnmanagedType.LPArray` You're getting an array...
- `ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPStr` ...of standard C strings...
- `SizeParamIndex = 1` ...and the size of that array is specified by the second parameter.

The C strings are copied and converted to `System.String` instances by the .NET marshaler before the invocation of your C# method. So if you need to pass dynamically generated strings to C#, you `malloc` them, then you call `gSetStringValuesCB`, and you can `free` them immediately afterwards, all from the C code, as .NET has its own copy of the data.

---

You can refer to [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.unmanagedtype.aspx):

> `UnmanagedType.LPArray`:
>
> > A pointer to the first element of a C-style array. When marshaling from managed to unmanaged code, the length of the array is determined by the length of the managed array. **When marshaling from unmanaged to managed code, the length of the array is determined from the `MarshalAsAttribute.SizeConst` and `MarshalAsAttribute.SizeParamIndex` fields**, optionally followed by the unmanaged type of the elements within the array when it is necessary to differentiate among string types.
>
> `UnmanagedType.LPStr`:
>
> > A single byte, null-terminated ANSI character string. You can use this member on the `System.String` and `System.Text.StringBuilder` data types.
>
> `MarshalAs.SizeParamIndex`:
>
> > Indicates the zero-based parameter that contains the count of array elements, similar to `size_is` in COM.

Comment: Thanks! SizeParamIndex  was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score -1):

I came up with far from optimal solution:

```
public delegate void MyManagedDelegate([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeConst=10)]string[] values, int valueCount);
```

This is not working if called like this:

```
char *Values[]= {"One", "Two", "Three"};
NativeCallDelegate(Values, 3);
```

I could have fixed size 10 array where the values are copied and that is always passed to delegate. This is not what I want. I wonder if there is good solution to this...