# Marshalling strings between managed code and native DLL

Tags: c#, c, dll, marshalling, unmarshalling

I'm trying to implement a License Manager module.
I've written the core code in `C`, and expect to write wrappers in `C#` to get it up.
The `native dll` has exports of this form:

```
typedef void (__stdcall *DMTypedef)(const char * const iMsg);
typedef int (__stdcall *RKTypedef)(
    const int (__stdcall *validator)
        (const char * const iKey, const char * const iAppID));

__declspec(dllexport) const void __stdcall initWindowManager(DMTypedef iDisplayMsg, RKTypedef iReadKey);
```

Basically, I wanted to separate the IO implementation from the Licensing Module.
Hence, caller would need to call `initWindowManager()` before proceeding with other code.

I've managed to write marshaling-code this far, but part of it doesn't seem to work as I expected. Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace LicenseManagerWrapper
{
    unsafe public static class Plugin_License
    {
        internal const string NativeDLLPath = @".\LicenseManagerNative.dll";

        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public delegate void DMDelegate(
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
            string iMsg
            );

        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public delegate int ValDelegate(
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
            string key,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
            string appID
            );

        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public delegate int RKDelegate(ValDelegate validator);

        [DllImport(NativeDLLPath,
            CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        private static extern void initWindowManager(
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]
            DMDelegate displayMessage,

            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]
            RKDelegate readKey
            );

        public static void initWM(DMDelegate iDisplayMessage, RKDelegate iReadKey)
        {
            initWindowManager(iDisplayMessage, iReadKey);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm working on `Visual Studio 12`, `64-bit` on `.NET 4.0`.
The debugger shows correct function call sequence, however when I reach to the implementation code in `readkey()` for `RKDelegate`, in `C#`, when control reaches to `validate()` for `ValDelegate` in native code, the `char *` pointers are not correct, and debugger shows `bad-pointer`. Can someone tell what I'm doing wrong?
I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35986459/how-to-call-c-sharp-delegate-to-pass-array-of-strings-from-native-c-simplest-way) post, but could not still figure out the problem here. Can someone tell, what I'm doing wrong?
Apologize, for the lengthy post. Here's an attempt at a graphic representation:

```
+------------------------------+                            +------------------------------+
|          Native DLL          |                            |         Managed Code         |
+------------------------------+                            +------------------------------+
|      initWindowManager()<----|----------------------------|-------- displayMessage()     |
|          validate()----------|----------------------------|-------> readKey()            |
|                              |                            |                              |
|                              |                            |                              |
|                              |                            |                              |
+------------------------------+                            +------------------------------+
```

Comment: Works correctly here (32 bits and 64 bits, .NET 4.0, VS 2013). Tested both with `DMDelegate` and `RKDelegate` as static methods and as instance methods... The smell test is OK... I've watched your code quite much and it smells OK... You put a little too many `const` for my taste, but that isn't a problem...

Comment: There's at least one superfluous `const`. :)
Is it because of passing C# implementation, as is to native code?
How can I specify calling convention here?

Comment: As I've written the code is correct... It is probably one of the more precise marshalling code I've seen on SO. The error is somewhere else. Ah... and the `unsafe` is useless (but no problem)

Comment: I shall check again. I'll come back if I find something. Thanks.

Comment: Bug disappeared magically on opening disassembly view! :) Heisenbug? :):) I'll look more...

Comment: Actually, when I tested by removing breakpoints in the actual validate(), in native code, the bug dissipates. Also, when run standalone outside IDE, modules seem to function as expected. In my understanding, it is probably different call-convention marshaling in Visual Studio debug-hook(?) mechanism. Maybe someone could explain.

Comment: Are you debugging in Debug or Release mode? In Release mode sometimes "things" can't be debugged

Comment: "I've written the core code in C" --> that code is missing from this post, suggest including it here.

Comment: Ah, you're right! I was debugging in Release configuration. Debug configuration : No issues.

Comment: I cannot release the actual implementation code, besides it was more of marshaling issue, as the parameters themselves arrived incorrect. Thus I only included the prototypes.